# Put variable In onClick function instead of value

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to output button using PHP to HTML

```
$n1, $n2 = variable from DB after SELECT.

echo "<button class='scr' value='$n1 $n2' onClick='sFat(value)'>$name1 $name2</button>";
```

It is working and onClick does fire the function I want.

Now, I think, why not I put the variable directly into the Function like below:

```
echo "<button class='scr' onClick='sFat('$n1 $n2')'>$name1 $name2</button>";
```

but it won't work, i even try others like:

```
echo "<button class='scr' onClick=sFat('$n1 $n2')>$name1 $name2</button>"; 
echo "<button class='scr' onClick="sFat('".$n1."' '".$n2."')">$name1 $name2</button>";
```

but still not working, what is the difference here? Why? Anyone knows?

Comment: Sounds like, Concatenation is not proper here.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to concatenate the strings here can be really difficult. If you do achieve it, it's still difficult to make modifications to, and for anyone else to read.

My solution would be to not try and do this. Set the desired variables elsewhere and call them.

```
//$n1, $n2 = variable from DB after SELECT.

echo "<script> var ns1 = ".$ns1."</script>";
echo "<script> var ns2 = ".$ns2."</script>";

echo "<button class='scr' onClick='sFat(n1, n2);'>$name1 $name2</button>";
```

I should also note that I assumed your js function sFat() accepted two parameters, rather than a concatenated string of ns1 and ns2.